# File upload selenium using sendKeys

Tags: java, selenium, file-upload, automation, sendkeys

My situation is that I am automating testing file upload feature. Now the automation ci works on another machine/box and the browser is opened in another machine(s) for the automation testing. I am able to package (add the test input file to be uploaded) in the jar. But the jar is in another another machine as mentioned above and the browser is in another machine(s). Since the browser machine is not fixed and picked up at automation runtime, so how can I have the input file which I need to upload available on the machine where browser is running.

I tried to copy the file after extracting it from the jar, but obviously it doesn't get copied in the browser machine(s), from where it is uploaded.

Is it even possible to have that file available in the browser machine(s)?

Comment: Please change the question title to something relevant to what you are actually asking.

Comment: @JeffC sure, something like remote boxes file upload?

Comment: Something like "How do I automatically get an input file to a remote machine where scripts are run?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you can do is putting the uploading file in to a shared folder which can be accessed from all the running machines. And give the file location from the shared folder. 
You can give the sendKeys command to the upload field like below

```
upload_textfield.sendKeys("\\shared_Folder\upload.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

static WebDriver driver;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, FindFailed {

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "E:\\doftware\\geckodriver-v0.10.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
    driver =new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1&osid=1");

    driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("emailaddress");
    driver.findElement(By.id("next")).click();
    Thread.sleep(500);
    driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys("Password");
    driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='T-I J-J5-Ji T-I-KE L3']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(500);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='a1 aaA aMZ']")).click();

    org.sikuli.script.Pattern open= new org.sikuli.script.Pattern("C:\\Users\\narendra\\Desktop\\test\\filename.PNG");
    org.sikuli.script.Pattern open1= new org.sikuli.script.Pattern("C:\\Users\\narendra\\Desktop\\test\\open.PNG");

    org.sikuli.script.Screen scr= new org.sikuli.script.Screen();
    scr.setAutoWaitTimeout(30);
    scr.type(open, "C:\\Users\\narendra\\Desktop\\test\\searchButton");
    scr.click(open1);
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Comment: sorry my bad , I have used sikuli API for file upload in Gmail ,rather than using autoIT , U can try this code this is quite easy .